# Git Clone Fails with inflate: data stream error (invalid distance code)

Tags: git

A problem occurred when trying to duplicate the Git repository I created.
There are several similar repositories, but since other repositories could be reproduced successfully, there seem to be problems with this repository.
What should I do to solve this problem?

The errors I'm seeing are the following when running a git clone:

```
client$ git clone --depth 1 git@host:/opt/git/project.git
Cloning into 'project'...
remote: Counting objects: 575, done.
remote: error: inflate: data stream error (invalid distance code)
remote: error: corrupt loose object 'b197fe2367c199e8b45d86cd62ba00446888bc58'
remote: fatal: loose object b197fe2367c199e8b45d86cd62ba00446888bc58 (stored in objects/b1/97fe2367c199e8b45d86cd62ba00446888bc58) is corrupt
error: git upload-pack: git-pack-objects died with error.
fatal: git upload-pack: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
remote: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
fatal: early EOF
```

Run a `git fsck`.

```
// Remote Repository
git@host:/opt/git/project.git $ git fsck --full
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
error: inflate: data stream error (invalid code lengths set)
error: unable to unpack 3bbe11c4a6220a9ce544a3b32b3976a509a0cf3a header
error: inflate: data stream error (invalid code lengths set)
fatal: loose object 3bbe11c4a6220a9ce544a3b32b3976a509a0cf3a (stored in objects/3b/be11c4a6220a9ce544a3b32b3976a509a0cf3a) is corrupt
```

Comment: Run a `git fsck` in the source repository.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.
I ran git fsck.

Comment: Clearly your remote repository is corrupt. You'll need to look into recovery or repair.